# How can I force to use specific package version while running go mod download?

Tags: go

go.mod file

```
go 1.13

require (
  ...
  gorm.io/gorm v1.20.5
)
```

When I run `go mod download` then my go.mod file becomes

```
go 1.13

require (
  ...
  gorm.io/gorm v1.20.7
)
```

How can I stop this upgrade while running `go mod download`?

Comment: You may not be able to. It's possible that one of your other dependencies depends on `v1.20.7`

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for the reply. I'll check that.

Comment: Use `go mod why` to query who needs this module

Comment: @Flimzy My other package has dependency on `v1.20.7` so it is automatically upgrading. Is there any other possibility that it may not work?

Comment: Then you need to downgrade that other dependency to a version that doesn't require v1.20.7.

Comment: Although, I do have to wonder what's wrong with just using v1.20.7?

Answer (score 3):

You can try `-mod=readonly` when running code

reference is here https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-updates

> The -mod=readonly flag prevents commands from automatically updating
> go.mod. However, if a command needs to perform an action that would
> update to go.mod, it will report an error. For example, if go build is
> asked to build a package not provided by any module in the build list,
> go build will report an error instead of looking up the module and
> updating requirements in go.mod.